# How to check if an ArrayList contains a specific value

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me why these is not working? If these work for me it will answer all my questions, please help me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    if (Scanner.listOfBarcodes.contains(records.get(i).getsid())) {
        jsonObject.put("attendance","Present");
    } else {
        jsonObject.put("attendance","Absent");
    }
```

`listOfBarcodes` is an `ArrayList` which contains a bunch of scanned barcode values which are student id numbers like `3924,3922...`

But it is always putting Absent in the `JSONObject`. Why is that happening? Please help me.

This is my serializable java class:

```
public class Student {

    private String sid;

    public void setsid(String sid){
        this.sid=sid;
    }

    public String getsid(){
        return sid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does listOfBarcodes contain integer values or string values?

Comment: @RyanWilson listOfBarcodes contains a string value

Comment: So when you set a break point at your if statement, listOfBarcodes has values in it?

Comment: @RyanWilson yes has values i have seen it by using log

Comment: Is it possible there is some whitespace or newline characters in the values in records? If so, try trimming your values and possibly setting each to lowercase before calling contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be able to help better with a bit more of your code to be sure of the answer, but I believe the problem is the function `contains()` expects to gets as a parameter an object of the same type of the ArrayList it is called from.

You need to debug it and check the that return value of `records.get(i).getsid()` has the same type as the ArrayList `listOfBarcodes`.

Maybe try to assign it to a temp value as follow and check what it returns and compare to this temp item, the problem could be in saving the values not in retrieving it *(Your call could be returning null)* as follows:

```
String tempSid = records.get(i).getsid();
if (Scanner.listOfBarcodes.contains(tempSid)) {
        jsonObject.put("attendance","Present");
    }
```

Comment: thank you  opened my eye its all my fault there was new line character in my listofBarcodes that is why its not matching the two values now i Added new line to the tempsid its working fine

Comment: I am glad I helped, yea those things usually happen! Good luck ;)